# Добавление записи в БД (связанные таблицы)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Недавно начал изучение Spring и столкнулся с проблемой.
В моём приложении есть 2 таблицы. Pc и PcCharact, эти таблицы связаны между собой по Id.
Как мне выполнить добавление нового PcCharact? В обычной (не связанной) таблице я конструктором забирал параметры и вставлял их. Но в данной ситуации так сделать не получается, потому что столбца с pc_id как поля нету, оно создаётся само Hibernate'ом. 
Вот код контроллера:

```
@Controller
public class PcCharactsController {

final private PcRepo pcRepo;
final private PcCharRepo pcCharRepo;

public PcCharactsController(PcRepo pcRepo, PcCharRepo pcCharRepo) {
    this.pcRepo = pcRepo;
    this.pcCharRepo = pcCharRepo;
}

//СПИСОК ХАРАКТЕРИСТИК ПО ID КОМПЬЮТЕРА
@GetMapping("pc/{id}/")
public String pcCharList(@PathVariable int id, Model model) throws Exception{

    Pc pc = pcRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("PostId " + id + " not found"));
    List<PcChars> pcChars = pc.getChars();
    model.addAttribute("model", pc.getName());
    model.addAttribute("pcChars", pcChars);
    return "charList";
}

//ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ ХАРАКТЕРИСТИКИ
@PostMapping("pc/{id}/")
public String addCharact(){

    return "charList";
}
```

Код модели Pc:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pc")
public class Pc {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String name;
private int price;

public Pc(){}

public Pc(String name, int price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "pc_id")
private List<PcChars> chars = new ArrayList<>();

public List<PcChars> getChars() {
    return chars;
}

public void setChars(List<PcChars> chars) {
    this.chars = chars;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}
```

И код PcChars:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pcChars")
public class PcChars {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;


private String name;
private String value;



public PcChars(){}

public PcChars(String name, String value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}

@ManyToOne
private Pc pc;



public Pc getPc() {
    return pc;
}

public void setPc(Pc pc) {
    this.pc = pc;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

Что нужно написать в addcharact в контроллере? Столько перепробовал вариантов, но ничего не работает нормально.

Comment: Как минимум, должны появиться еще два бина `@Repository`

Comment: Они есть. Мне надо как-то достать @RequestParameter'ом pc_id или что-то типа того. Но я не знаю как мне добавить его в таблицу характеристики, потому что конструктор я не могу использовать, ибо поле pc_id не определено, а просто как свойство в JoinColumn